# How do you find or understand acronyms?

Tags: jewish-books, acronyms

I've heard that the acronym in a [sefer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1429) usually appears in the sefer in its full form somewhere before the acronym does, and in many cases I find this, but sometimes I do not, and cannot figure out the acronym, and others fail to know also. How do you know what it means? Is there a dictionary or way to figure out from the text?

Comment: Thanks for bringing your question to Mi Yodeya; welcome! You may wish to [read more about how the site works](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). Please also consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557) to more of the site's features.

Comment: http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/asi.21367/abstract

Comment: RELATED: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/128180/22460

Answer (score 8):

There is a sefer called Otzar Roshei Teivos -  see it [here](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/47664/%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA---%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%A8%D7%AA) and there is an older sefer with the same name that I can't find online, but probably your average Jewish book store would be able to get it for you.  (Asuming you aren't needing to look these up when near a computer and want a small sefer for reference.  The older sefer is smaller than the one I linked.)

Answer (score 5):

I use these websites to search for abbreviations.  They're not perfect, but they have a good number.

[קיצורים וראשי תיבות בעברית](http://www.kizur.co.il/home.php)

[ראשי תיבות](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=9)

Comment: See also http://hebrewbooks.org/34968

Comment: Also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hebrew_abbreviations