# Is there a website that has a list of Roshei Teivot in text format?

Tags: sources-mekorot, acronyms

I'm looking for a resource that has a list of Roshei Tevviot in **text** format. Where can I find this?

Comment: possible duplicate https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35753/759

Comment: @DoubleAA There's an answer there that has a list of books in PDF, but I'm looking for a text format where I can copy/paste.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mendel and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lists:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Hebrew_abbreviations
- https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_Targumim,_the_Talmud_Babli_and_Yerushalmi,_and_the_Midrashic_Literature/Hebrew_or_Aramaic_Abbreviations

Not a list, but it's a search form:

- http://www.kizur.co.il/search_word.php

PDF's of books that are OCR'd (so you can copy and paste):

- https://hebrewbooks.org/34968 also at [this url](https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/rt/rt00.pdf) Rashei Teivot, Avraham Yitzchak Shtern RAB"D Orăștie (Szászváros), 1926 Sighetul-Marmației

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for more answers. I wish I can place a bounty.

Comment: added Jastrow's list

Answer (score 4):

(Note: I'm the OP).

Since I haven't found any good resources on Roshei Teivot, I have decided to go ahead and create an app for a list of Roshei Teivot. You can look for it on the app/play store.

Edit, I have decided to post a link: (See [Is my answer considered spam](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5499/22460))

- [Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mendelg.otzar_roshei_teivot2)
- [IOS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/otzar-roshei-teivot-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99-%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA/id6444920898)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, Dicta has a Rabbinic R"T (is that roshei tevot or Rabbenu Tam?) - [Abbreviations Expander](https://abbreviation.dicta.org.il/). I use it and like it a lot.